# do I need to refer ThisWorkbook (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I do some VBA operations on specific sheets in a Workbook that may be copied later, enabling the end user to open more than one copy at a time (and filling the tables with different data).

**Question:**
Do I need to refer explicitly `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strMySheetName)` to avoid any code to operate on the sheet *with the same name* but *inside another copy* of the workbook (opened at the same time), or does the `Sheets` collection always refer to the workbook *the code resides in* (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`)?

Comment: It refers to the workbook it resides in.

Comment: or to be even more specific you can use `Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: No, the Sheets or Worksheets collection refers to the ActiveWorkbook not necessarily ThisWorkbook unless you qualify the parent workbook like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1"). It's the same as range or cells defaulting to the Activesheet if used without a parent worksheet reference in a public module code sheet. Use a With ThisWorkbook ... End With block so you don't have to repeat ThisWorkbook  too many times.

Comment: Fully qualifying your reference is analogous to using a condom:  "You don't have to use them all the time but eventually you are going to regret not having used it!"

Comment: Rather than ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strMySheetName) everywhere, dim a variable to point to the worksheet and set that appropriately. Dim wsMySheet as Worksheet;Set wsMySheet = Thisworkbook.sheets(strmysheetname). Once set wsMysheet will always point to the right sheet

Comment: Doesn't the sheet codename always refer to `ThisWorkbook` when it's used.  e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1")` is the same as `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("TabNameFor_Sheet1").Range("A1")`?

Comment: In addition to my last comment I found [The only times you cannot use a sheets CodeName is when you reference a Sheet that is in a different Workbook to the one that the code resides.](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm).  I'd suggest using the codename - your users can then move sheets about and rename them but your code will still know what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : No you don't need to.

The default context of execution of the macro it the currently active Workbook.
So if your macro is launched through action on the Workbook sheets (calculate, widgets such as buttons, save or load events), there is no risk.

If your macro is cross-workbook, can be triggered by action on another workbook or intends to set focus, load, modify other workbooks, then its a must to specify `ThisWorkbook.`

As already mentionned in the comments of your questions, alternatives such as `Workbook("myworkbookname")` are better for disambiguation in many cases, but have side effect in case you change the filename.

Comment: Thank's for your answer - helped me to clarify my understanding. I decided to fully qualify using `ThisWorkbook` anyway, following TinMan's comment above. You never know - especially if you tend to reuse code later (as I do). (`Workbook("MyWorkbookName")` is no option in my case: my users will have to rename the workbook to personalize it.)